# Requests.get connections with time delay not working correctly with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to implement RequestsThrottler in my requests.get operation, which queries about 50 websites.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RequestsThrottler/0.2.2

Code before RequestsThrottler (which works):

```
secondCrawlRequest = requests.get(row[6],headers=http_headers, timeout=5)
raw_html = secondCrawlRequest.text
SoupParser = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
results = SoupParser.find('div', attrs={'style':'padding-left:10px;width:98%'})

for para in results.findAll('p'):
    para_text = para.text.strip()
    list_of_paras.append(para_text)
```

Code with RequestsThrottler added (which fails)

```
with BaseThrottler(name='base-throttler', delay=1.5) as bt:
     secondCrawlRequest = requests.get(row[6],headers=http_headers, timeout=5)
     reqs = [secondCrawlRequest for i in range(0, 5)]
     throttled_requests = bt.multi_submit(reqs)
     # where does responses get passed too?
     responses = [tr.response for tr in throttled_requests]
     raw_html = secondCrawlRequest.text
     SoupParser = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
     results = SoupParser.find('div', attrs={'style':'padding-left:10px;width:98%'})
for para in results.findAll('p'):
    para_text = para.text.strip()
    list_of_paras.append(para_text)
```

The code fails, because I'm not passing the 'responses' parameter correctly.

My error is this:

File "/Users/helloWorld/Python Projects/Harvesters - web01_harvester.py", line 264, in 
    for para in results.findAll('p'):
NameError: name 'results' is not defined

How do I pass the 'responses' parameter correctly?

Comment: Please show [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Because in the code you've showed is an indentation error, but if that is corrected it would not result in the error you describe. Regarding the comment in that code: `responses` isn't used anywhere. At least not in the code you show.

Comment: I fixed the indentation error in my post.  I posted the code that worked before adding RequestsThrottler and the code that doesn't work after adding RequestsThrottler.  I'm not sure how to pass "responses' for my soup operation.

Comment: I still very much doubt you are getting the error you describe.  This could only happen if the `BaseThrottler` context manager suppresses an exception occurring in the `with` block so the assignment to `results` isn't reached. Anyway, what you named `secondCrawlRequest` isn't a `Request` instance but a response instance.  Compare this with the example code at the PyPI page you've linked to.

Comment: What's the point of throttling _one_ request anyway? The ”before” code just shows one request, not 50 like described in the question.  You need to integrate the throttler at a level in the code ”above” all those requests. If you use `with` the code responsible for requesting all pages has to be within that block, either directly or indirectly via function or method calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The throttler has to be put ”above” all the requests, so I assume there is a loop over rows around the working but unthrottled code.

```
paragraphs = list()
with BaseThrottler(delay=1.5) as throttler:
    throttled_requests = throttler.multi_submit(
        [
            requests.Request(row[6], headers=http_headers, timeout=5)
            for row in rows
        ]
    )

for request in throttled_requests:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.get_response().text, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.find('div', attrs={'style': 'padding-left:10px;width:98%'})
    for paragraph in div.find_all('p'):
        paragraphs.append(paragraph.text.strip())
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  I tried adding it inside a try block, which produced this error:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/helloWorld/Python Projects/Harvesters - web01_harvester.py", line 290, in <module>
    for request in throttled_requests:
NameError: name 'throttled_requests' is not defined

Comment: That could only be happening if `BaseThrottler` instances used as context managers silently ”swallow” exceptions. Which would be bug. Maybe take this to the author(s) of `BaseThrottler`.